# Books for Random Process

Tags: reference-request

I have been using Sheldon Ross' book all through undergrad and recently I've noticed that it does not cover random process at all.

What are some good references on this material that does not treat the subject on a graduate level or from a measure theory perspective?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out Karlin's First and second courses in stochastic processes.

Comment: Sheldon Ross has more than one book.  "Introduction to Probability Models" does cover various sorts of random processes reasonably well.